# An unhandled exception occured an unhandled exception of type 'system.invalidoperationexception' occurred in system.data.dll in c#

Tags: c#

I am using Visual Studio 2013 and SQL Server 2012. I want to save my data in the database but it gives:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll

My code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbx"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("ups_StudentInsertDetails"))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Name", textBox1.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Email", textBox2.Text);
                //then open connection
                conn.Open();
                //Execute Reader(select ststement)
                //Execute Scalar(select ststement)
                //Executenonquery (Insert , update or delete)
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Data saved successfully!");

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Error:
[image: error]

Comment: Please press view detail and show me

Answer (score 1):

Open your sqlconnection like this and associate it with the sqlcommand.
See the code changes below highlighted in comments.

```
Private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbx"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
    conn.open();  //Open Connection
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("ups_StudentInsertDetails",conn)) //Pass connection to thesqlcommand
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Name", textBox1.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Email", textBox2.Text);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Data saved successfully!");
        }
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

`SqlCommand` does not contain the `SqlConnection` you are opening. in the first place. You can make the code easier to drop the second using and open the connection at the command before executing it:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbx"].ConnectionString;
     using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
     {
         SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("ups_StudentInsertDetails", conn);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Name", textBox1.Text);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Email", textBox2.Text);

         //then open connection
         cmd.Connection.Open();

         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         MessageBox.Show("Data saved successfully!");
    } 
 }
```

[More info on the MSDN website with example at the bottom](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx)